# How can I simulate two fluorophores with a reticle?

Tags: optics, microscopy, coherence, fluorescence

Fluorophores typically emit in an *incoherent* fashion.  I thought I could simulate two fluorophores (e.g. single molecule fluors) with a reticle.  My concept was to make two **small** holes in a chrome photomask very close together (e.g. 200 - 500 nm).  I was going to use this to characterize an optical system that would eventually be used for measuring single molecule emission.

However, if I back illuminate the reticle with an LED, I'm concern that the two holes in the mask will act **coherently**; they will be spatially coherent with a constant phase offset.  This will produce an interference pattern between the two holes (i.e. spatial coherence).  This doesn't happen when two fluorophores emit.

1. Am I right to be concerned?
2. Is there a way to make them incoherent?

Comment: One typical way is to put a rotating phase sheet in front of one of the holes. That randomizes the relative phases.  But here's the question: does your equipment design depend on incoherence to report "dual source" detection? Are you imaging or just collecting the light?

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with the "rotating ground glass" architecture.  From a mutual coherence standpoint (see Goodman, Statistic Optics), each emitted must be mutually incoherent.  That means that they should not interfere.  To create this scenario, one would have to ensure that the phase of the two "holes" in the reticle had random, uncorrelated phase.  This seems hard to achieve in practice.

Comment: probably easier to use commercial fluorescent beads (of 100nm diam.), or qdots ?

Comment: Beads are subject to quenching and bleaching. I'm looking for a methodology of testing an optical system in a way that can be used in pilot production.

Answer (score 0):

1) I think you are right to be worried. You would have to illuminate your two apertures with a light source with a spatial coherence smaller than 200 - 500 nm. It is I am afraid impossible to get a spatial coherence below the diffraction limit. Simply imagine you would image one single molecule with a very high NA objective on one of the holes, it would be impossible to illuminate just one hole.

2) I can think of a - not so practical - way to get around it. The ingredients you need are A) illumination below the diffraction limit B) the two sources must be incoherent. You could make two metal coated waveguides (like the ones used in aperture NSOM measurements) that end at the two holes. You could for instance make a long waveguide on top of a glass plate and illuminate it from two sides. In the middle of the waveguide you could make a deep but narrow trench that you fill with a metal with a very low penetration length. In that way you have two waveguides that end at the same place but are isolated. You will probably have quite low throughput and quite some work to do to get it working....

Maybe it is easier to just take two single molecules?

Comment: Single molecules are subject to quenching and bleaching.  I'm looking for a methodology of testing an optical system in a way that can be used in pilot production.